# Matplotlib set_data not showing a line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In previous versions of my code I cleared the plot and replotted the data up until the most recently calculated data point. In an attempt to speed up the plotting, I am trying to switch to using `set_data` so I am not clearing every step. Unfortunately, I am unable to produce a line with this change.

Below you can see my attempt at using `set_data` for the top plot, but I left the original method for the bottom one.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

frames = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, frames)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [])
line2, = ax2.plot([], [])
ax1.set_xlim(x.min()*1.1, x.max()*1.1)
ax1.set_ylim(y1.min()*1.1, y1.max()*1.1)

def animate(i):
    line1.set_data(x[i], y1[i])
    
    ax2.cla()
    ax2.plot(x[:i], y2[:i])
    ax2.set_xlim(x.min()*1.1, x.max()*1.1)
    ax2.set_ylim(y2.min()*1.1, y2.max()*1.1)
    
    plt.pause(0.01)

for i in range(20*frames):
    animate(i%frames)
```

Comment: You go probably not far enough. The matplotlib plot is a scene graph, so instead of constructing the graph anew for each frame, what should work better is to construct it once and then just manipulate the data of the objects, as you intended with `set_data` for the lines. // Why do you not use the `matplotlib.animate` framework?

Comment: That was what I was hoping to achieve with `set_data` but I cannot seem to get anything to show up. Regarding `matplotlib.animate`, I am confused about how the function works for me to apply it to this project, which is why I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake with this problem was a pretty basic mistake and was based on misunderstanding the use of the `set_data` function. I thought that I needed to pass into it a new data *point*, but really you need to pass the entire data set, but with updated points.

So, the code ended up looking as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

frames = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, frames)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [])
line2, = ax2.plot([], [])
ax1.set_xlim(x.min()*1.1, x.max()*1.1)
ax1.set_ylim(y1.min()*1.1, y1.max()*1.1)

def animate(i):
    line1.set_data(x[:i], y1[:i])
    
    ax2.cla()
    ax2.plot(x[:i], y2[:i])
    ax2.set_xlim(x.min()*1.1, x.max()*1.1)
    ax2.set_ylim(y2.min()*1.1, y2.max()*1.1)
    
    plt.pause(0.01)

for i in range(20*frames):
    animate(i%frames)
```

And, as suggested by [@Lutz Lehmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088138/lutz-lehmann) in the comments, I could do this pretty easily using `FuncAnimation`, as shown below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

frames = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, frames)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [])
line2, = ax2.plot([], [])
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_xlim(x.min()*1.1, x.max()*1.1)
    ax.set_ylim(y1.min()*1.1, y1.max()*1.1)


def animate(i):
    line1.set_data(x[:i], y1[:i])
    line2.set_data(x[:i], y2[:i])
    return (line1, line2), 

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, interval=0.01)
```